# How can I make a background image repeat using React gatsby-background-image?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

Following the instructions in the `gatsby-background-image` [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/), I'm able to add a full width background image to a component by including the following in my component

```
    <BackgroundImage fluid={backgroundImage.node.childImageSharp.fluid}>
      {children}
    </BackgroundImage>
```

This results in the following "stretched" background:

[image]

However, I do not want my image to be the full width of the component. Instead, I would like my background image to repeat within my component to achieve the following:

[image: Correct Image]

I see that styling of the background image is [supported](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/#styling--passed-through-styles), but I'm not sure how correctly style the background image to make it repeat. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `style={{backgroundSize: '', backgroundPosition: '', backgroundRepeat: '',}}` [Styling & Passed Through Styles](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/#styling--passed-through-styles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `style` object as shown in the [Styling & Passed Through Styles section](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/#styling--passed-through-styles).

```
  <BackgroundImage fluid={backgroundImage.node.childImageSharp.fluid} 
                   style={{ backgroundRepeat: 'repeat', backgroundSize: '200' }}>
      {children}
    </BackgroundImage>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! When I tried adding the `backgroundRepeat` style element on it's own, the background image was still "stretched". Building on your suggestion, if I also set the `backgroundSize` style element then it works! That is, `style={{ backgroundRepeat: 'repeat', backgroundSize: '200' }}`.